# Load 64-bit raw image file in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am wondering how to load [this image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3816350/Posts/image.bdat) in python. I can load it in imageJ using the pictures settings, but I cannot figure out how to load it in python.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname = 'Downloads/image.bdat'
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    infile.seek(4)
    data = np.fromfile(infile, dtype='>f8').reshape(1024, 256)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='gray')
ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])
fig.colorbar(im)
fig.savefig('figure_1.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Let me back up and explain what's going on.

First off, to read "raw" data in from a file into a numpy array, use `numpy.fromfile` with the appropriate dtype and then reshape it.

You have most of the information we need (shape, offset into the file where the data begins, and dtype). However, there are a few other things we need to know: the endianness of the data and the order of the array (usually C or F ordered).

To read data at an offset with `numpy.fromfile`, it's easiest to `seek` to that offset before calling the function.  In your case, you have an offset into the file of 4 bytes before the data starts (presumably the first 4 bytes are the image size/shape or something else).

That gives us:

```
fname = 'Downloads/image.bdat'
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    infile.seek(4)
```

Next well use `fromfile`.  However, the first thing you're likely to try will yield an odd result:

```
fname = 'Downloads/image.bdat'
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    infile.seek(4)
    data = np.fromfile(infile, dtype=np.float64).reshape(1024, 256)
```

[image]

Those values seem unreasonable, and we're getting noise as an image.  We've probably used the wrong datatype.  Based on your information, we know it's a 64-bit float of some sort, so the most likely scenario is a difference in [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  Most systems are little-endian these days, but a lot of file formats use big-endian for a variety of reasons.  In numpy, you can specify a big-endian dtype by switching over to the string specification for dtypes and using a `>` to indicate big-endian.  (`<` indicates little-endian and `=` specifies using the native byte-order)

That gets us the rest of the way there:

```
fname = 'Downloads/image.bdat'
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    infile.seek(4)
    data = np.fromfile(infile, dtype='>f8').reshape(1024, 256)
```

Note that we could have also use the `byteswap` method, if you find it more readable:

```
fname = 'Downloads/image.bdat'
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    infile.seek(4)
    data = np.fromfile(infile, dtype=np.float64).reshape(1024, 256)
    data = data.byteswap()
```

---

There's one final piece of information that we need in general: The [ordering of the array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).  For 2D arrays, there's only C and Fortran ordering.  For higher-dimensional arrays, there are technically other orderings, but they're almost never used.

In this case, it's C-ordered (or "row-major"), so the likely first guess (`.reshape(nrows, ncols)`) works correctly.  If it was fortran ordered, we'd swap the number or rows and columns in the reshape and then transpose it.

```
fname = 'Downloads/image.bdat'
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    infile.seek(4)
    data = np.fromfile(infile, dtype='>f8').reshape(256, 1024).T
```

Alternatively, for better readability, you could do:

```
data = np.fromfile(infile, dtype='>f8').reshape(1024, 256, order='F')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for both the solution to this problem and the incredible step-by-step instructions on how you got there. I only wish I could vote this up more than once. 
I had tried to use np.fromfile, and arrived at the same noisy image that you showed. Once again, I was fooled by a big-endian image!